# Energy Diagram for Propane

Tags: organic-chemistry, energy, hydrocarbons, conformers

I've been unable to find an energy diagram for propane either in my book or online via Google. So I resorted to making my own. I suspect that propane isn't covered because it's essentially the same deal as ethane - we can have one staggered conformation and one eclipsed conformation (only in propane it's a methyl eclipsing a hydrogen, not hydrogens eclipsing each other).

So I drew the Newman projections and an energy diagram.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your diagram is correct.  Here is a [link](http://www.uwplatt.edu/~sundin/353/image/l960925f.gif) to an on-line energy diagram for propane and here is the diagram itself[image]